# Check if key attributes are not None in class in Python

Tags: python, attributes, key

I'm newbie in Python. I'm looking the way to check if important for me attributes (not all attributes of the object) are not None. I know how to do it in ugly way but I thought it must be a better way. Let me explain:
Let assume that i have class Material

```
class Material(self, att_a = None, att_b = None, att_c = None, att_d = None):
    self.att_a = att_a  #key attribute
    self.att_b = att_b  #key attribute
    self.att_c = att_c
    self.att_d = att_d

def check_key_value():
    if self.att_a == None:
         return False
    if self.att_b == None:
         return False
    return True

M1 = Material()
M1.att_a = 85

if M1.check_key_value() == True:
    ex1 = M1.att_a * 5
    ex2 = M1.att_b / 5
```

I know that must be smart way to handle with this.

Thanks in advance

Comment: `return any(k is none for k in (self.att, self.attb))` maybe? Your function looks fine to me.

Comment: yes, but what if I have 10 or more attributes. It's getting to be not smart like Python is :)

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga except that: `if M1.check_key_value == True:` is always false: typo missing `()` doesn't call the function.

Comment: Well, then `any(k is none for k in list_of_attributes)`

Comment: I corrected typo. Thanks @Jean-FrançoisFabre

Comment: just do `if M1.check_key_value():` don't _ever_ compare to `True`

Comment: Don't use `== True`. Just use `if M1.check_key_value()`; `if` already knows how to test for boolean values.

Comment: When all attributes are `None` then I have `TypeError: NoneType object is not iterable`

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't allow key attributes to be `None`, to begin with, and the `__init__()` method should be used as follows:

```
class Material(object):

    def __init__(self, att_a, att_b, att_c=None, att_d=None)
        self.att_a = att_a
        self.att_b = att_b
        self.att_c = att_c
        self.att_d = att_d
        print("Success!")
        return None
```

Try this out and you will see that `None` values for attributes `att_a` and `att_b` will not be accepted when instantiating the object. Examples:

The code

```
M1 = Material(att_a=0.3, att_b=0.34)
```

outputs

```
Success!
```

and

```
M1 = Material()
```

outputs

```
TypeError: __init__() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'att_a' and 'att_b'
```